# Casting a complex object to a string in Haskell?

Tags: string, object, haskell, output

I am currently writing a program that stores multiple custom data types as a "film" type.

```
type Director = String
type Title = String
type Year = Int
type Rating = (String, Int)
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, Rating)

createFilm :: Title -> Director -> Year -> Rating -> Film
createFilm w x y z = (w, x, y, z)

makeRating :: String -> Int -> Rating
makeRating x y = (x, y)

addToDatabase :: IO () 
addToDatabase = do
    putStr "Enter the title of the film: "
    title <- getLine
    putStr "Enter the director's name: "
    director <- getLine
    putStr "Enter the year the movie was released: "
    year <- getLine
    putStr "Please enter your name: "
    name <- getLine
    putStrLn "Please enter your rating: "
    rating <- getLine
    print (createFilm title director (read year) (makeRating name (read rating)))
```

An example output of the print at the end is `("Test", "Test", 1900, ("Test", 5))`
How do I turn this into a usable string that I can later write to a text file?

e.g, directly convert this exact output as `"("Test", "Test", 1900, ("Test", 5))"`

Comment: use `show` perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want `"("Test", "Test", 1900, ("Test", 5))"`, then `show film` will give you exactly that.

If I might make a suggestion however, instead of structuring everything with type synonyms, create your own types. There are quite a few benefits, since you can't mix up what exactly a 4 element tuple represents and you can provide better abstractions. Maybe it's not worth it now, but as a if you were to build this into something more sophisticated, proper types are a must.

```
type Director = String
type Title = String
type Year = Int
data Rating = Rating {ratingName :: String, ratingScore :: Int}
data Film = Film { title    :: Title
                 , director :: Director
                 , year     :: Year
                 , rating   :: Rating}
```

Now, depending on how you want things pretty printed there are a few choices. By default, you can add `deriving Show` to each of these and then once you have a `Film` value, use the function `show` to get the string

```
"Film {title = \"Test\",
       director = \"Test\",
       year = 1990, 
       rating = Rating {ratingName = \"Test\", ratingScore = 5}}"
```

Much prettier, however if you want something different, you can just add an

```
 instance Show Rating where
   show (Rating name value) = ...
 instance Show Film where
   show (Film title director year rating) = ...
       where ratingString = show rating
```

and now to get your pretty printed string, just call `show`.